# animate after jquery scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollto

I'm traying to animate a logo after scrolling animation or when i click any menu link but it's not working.

I got this code for animate scrolling:

```
jQuery(function() {
            jQuery('a').bind('click',function(event){
                var $anchor = jQuery(this);

                jQuery('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: jQuery($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
                }, 2000,'easeInOutExpo');

                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
```

then, to animate the logo, if the windows position change, i made this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery(window).bind('scroll',function(){
        var wscroll = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
        if(wscroll > 500){
            jQuery('#logo').delay(800).animate({
                    left:'+48px'
                    });
            }else if(wscroll < 500){
                jQuery('#logo').animate({
                    left:'-250px'
                    });
                }
                console.log(wscroll);
        });

});
```

[Here is](http://desarrollo.cbwagencia.com/consorcio/) the example

But this is not working, not at all.

Some guidance is appreciated. Tks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: console.log will cause the script to crash in Firefox.

Also, the real issue is you need to use .stop() on the animation. It seems to be continually running the animation.

Comment: That's right, after another 30 minutes checking the code, I tested with stop(true, false) and it worked perfect, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [ScrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plugin and `OnAfter` function:

```
$(...).scrollTo( 'SomeWhere', 1600, {onAfter:function(){ 
   //Your code
} } );
```

Answer (score 0):

i wrote simple example, maybe will help you. It working for me, but reaction of animation is quite slow ... don't know why :/

http://jsfiddle.net/pVHwY/1/

Answer (score 0):

You must any working scroll to plugin here's one the plugin to animate while scrolling [Jquery Scrolling Plugins](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-scrolling/top-15-jquery-scrolling/)